# C++ Automatically Exposing Class Members to Multiple APIs

Tags: c++, boilerplate

Short:
There are many clever libraries out there that allow you to expose a class' members for various purposes, such as serialisation, exposure to a lua environment, etc. The problem is that for each clever solution you have to register a class' stuff for each api, which results in a lot of work duplication and boilerplate.

What is a way that I can register a class and its members and methods *ONCE* with some kind of flags attached and get various autogenerated methods

Long:
Lets say I have a class:

```
class C {
public:
    int i;  // Some int
    vec3 v; // Some non-POD value
    int function(int foo, char bar) // Some function
    int hidden; // Some internal stuff I don't want exposed
        }
```

What I'd like to do is be able to mark various members and methods at declaration time to have them be put in the various boilerplate automatically:

So declaration might look like:

```
class C {
public:
    LUAREG JSON BINSER int i; // Marks member "i" to be exposed to the lua enviroment,
                              // JSON serialisable, binary serialisable
    JSON vec3 v; // Only exposed to JSON function

    LUAREG void someFunction() {} // Marks this method to be exposed to the lua enviroment
    }
```

Or perhaps writing one registration function that does all the declarations:

```
void C::register_class() {
    registrator::register_class<C>("C")
        .addData("i", &i, FLAG_LUA | FLAG_JSON | FLAG_BINARY_SERIALISABLE)
        .addFunction("someFunction", &someFunction, FLAG_LUA)
    .end_class()
    }
```

(I've seen this pattern some times - does this have a name?)
I want to be able to automatically generate various boilerplate functions for said class. For example:

```
/// Adds all fields with FLAG_JSON to a "json" object to be later serialised
void toJson(const C & c, json & j) {
    toJson(c.i, "i", j);
    toJson(c.v, "v", j);
    }

/// Binary seralises all members with flag FLAG_BINARY_SERIALISABLE and stores the result in s
void serialise(const C & c, string & s) {
    serialise(c.i, s);
    serialise(c.v, s);
    }

/// Registers all stuff with flag FLAG_LUA to some lua environment
void register_lua(lua_State * const L) {
        luaReg_FetchContext(L)::addClass("C")
            .addData("x", &C::x).comment("Some int") // generates documentation of "int x : Some int"
            .addData("v", &C::v).comment("Some vector")
            .addFunction("function", &C::function).comment("some function") // generates: "int function(int, char) : some function"
        .endClass()
        }

/// Register to some *other* lua environment (such as a read only context for rendering)
void register_lua_readonly(lua_State * const L2) {
        luaReg_FetchContext(L)::addClass("C")
            .addData("x", &C::x, false).comment("Some int")
        .endClass()
        }

/// Generates some user readable breakdown of all members
string dump() {
    ...
    }
```

Now you can see with many classes this will become very tedious, bloaty and error prone to do manually

What is the best way to approach this? I am tempted to use a macro to spit out the functions, but have no idea how to approach the registration stage. Cheers!

Comment: To answer your mini-question: the concept of a class constructed piecemeal with methods is called the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). The style of API where you're chaining parameters as methods is called a [fluent api](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/30166/builder-pattern-with-fluent-api)

Comment: Brainstorming how to accomplish the first style, you could try using templates to build the traits: `lua_reg<json<binser<T>>>` and then something like [Boost PFR](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) to aggregate the traits for registration, serializing, etc.

Comment: @parktomatomi for one thing, that will not supply the name of the variable

Comment: @darune Good point, I guess a macro is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this - I rolled my own reflection library - https://github.com/SnapperTT/STTR

```
class C {
public:
    int i;
    double d;
    int func(int z) const {
        return z;
        }

    static int static_var;
    static int static_func() { return 5; }
    };
int C::static_var = 7;

struct D : public C {
    int di;
    };

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    // Registration
    sttr::RegNamespace mNamespace("testns");
    mNamespace.beginClass<C>("C")
        .regField(&C::i, "i")
        .regField(&C::d, "d")
            .setUserFlags(0x00F00BAA) // Sets the user flags for the last added item
            .setUserString("You can use this for whatever")
            .setUserData((void *) &someStruct)
        .regField(&C::func, "func")

        .regField(&C::static_var, "static_var")
        .regField(&C::static_func, "static_func")
    .endClass()
    .findClass("C").beginClass<D>("D") // Class inherritance. Also you can just beginClass<D>("D") inside C
        .regField(&D::di, "di")
    .endClass();
}
```

The key to this solution is that I can attach flags to registered members (so LUA could be `1 << 0`, JSON could be `1 << 1`, etc.

Automatic json serialisation and lua registration is done via a visitor. The visitor checks if the members have the relevent flag and either does its thing or skips onto the next member.

I have also attempted to use RTTR: https://github.com/rttrorg/rttr - its a nice, if albeit bulky library. I rolled my own library because I didn't like the visitor interface and the voluminous template error messages.

Finally automatic documentation is done by running a script that does a bunch of regex find-and-substitutes to pick out cases of `typename Foo; /// Some documentation` and create a `static const char * const docv_Foo = "Some documentation";` and registers it. This does add an intermediate step to compilation but its not at all bad.